# Scrapy - CSS selectors

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to understand how CSS selectors work using Scrapy. but I definitely don't understand to navigate in several html tag.
For example, I'm trying to extract all the href link in the div id "portefeuille_bloc":

[image: code screenshot]

I tried this code but I can't identify where the mistake is:

```
response.css('div[id=portefeuille_bloc a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Furthermore, I tried to go deeper in the structure, and get all the h3 tag in the sub-division "portefeuille_bloc_bloc:

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: I think your main mistake was missing the ending square bracket after `portefeuille_bloc`.

Comment: Ooops.. yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
response.css('div#portefeuille_bloc a::attr(href)').getall()
```

See this doc page for more ideas:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`response.css('#portefeuille_bloc ::attr(href)').extract()`

There is no need to use HTML tags with `ids` and `classes`.